# Is there a term for when people speak words with sounds connected together?

Tags: terminology, pronunciation, speech, fast-speech-rules

For example, "I must take control like Kevin" can be said like "I mus-tay-control-I-Kevin" in some dialects because it flows significantly more easily than if you enunciate every word.

(Portmanteau is not the answer.)

Comment: Isn't this just normal connected speech? After all, no <SPACE> body <SPACE> speaks <SPACE> with <SPACE> spaces <SPACE> be <SPACE> tween <SPACE> their <SPACE> words. :) It's frankly unnatural that way, like listening to a robot.

Comment: It's basically just "slurring" your speech.

Comment: I don't think *like Kevin* shares the *k*; I hear two *k*'s — otherwise it sounds like *like heaven*. (American English)

Comment: @TinfoilHat - You've never heard someone who slurred all their words together?

Comment: @HotLicks — *mus-tay-control* isn't slurring words together — that just ordinary phonetics. If I hear you say *like-heaven* for *like Kevin* — yes, I hear a word slur. Don't drive.

Comment: @tchrist Your example is separating syllables, which is definitely unnatural. I've heard people talk with full enunciation before; there are definitely people who do it.

Comment: It sounds as if they do not know the language but are repeating the phonetics they have learned. They are missing the normal places of pauses and rhythms of a native speaker. Mumbling is another possibility.

Comment: It's ordinary English speech. Spelling has nothing to do with pronunciation (despite what you may have been taught), and nobody speaks the same (which is why you can tell who's speaking). So nobody pronounces things the same way, either. That's why English learners have to learn the spellings and pronunciations of English words separately; you can't predict the spellings from the pronunciation, and you can't predict the pronunciations from the spellings. So don't be surprised when they don't match.

Comment: It's called speaking. Not doing it is known as having a speech impediment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as *connected speech* or *fast speech processes* and involves a series of phenomena including *allophonic variation, reduced syllables, elision, assimilation,* and *coalescence* amongst others. These rules are all part of normal speech processes.

Answer (score -1):

[Cluttering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluttering) (Wikipedia) is a speech and communication disorder characterized by a rapid rate of speech, erratic rhythm, and poor syntax or grammar, making speech difficult to understand.

[Glib](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glib) (Merriam-webster Dictionary) marked by ease and fluency in speaking or writing often to the point of being insincere or deceitful

[Glibbery](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glibbery) (Merriam-webster Dictionary)(now chiefly dialectal) : smooth, slippery: (now chiefly dialectal) : not trustworthy : unreliable

Alternatively you can use the simple terms such as "rapid talker", "superfast speech", "superfluent" etc.